# how to call define_method in rails after_kind hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hook

when i call define_method in hook function :
error occurred:

```
undefined method `define_method' for #<Myentity:0x007f9e4eda5928>
```

here is an example:

```
class EntityInstance < ApplicationRecord

  after_find :define_relation

  def define_relation
    define_method "example" do |x|

    end
  end

end
```

How to change the context in hook method or how to use this function in hook method?

thx a lot!

Comment: We'll need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method) should be called in the context of the class.

Meaning, depending on where you want to define the method (either in singleton class of the instance of `Myentity` or in `Myentity` class) you should be using either

```
 def define_relation
   # define method available only to this particular instance of Myentity
   class_eval do
     define_method "example" do |x|
     end
   end
 end
```

or

```
 def define_relation
   # define a method available to all instances of Myentity class
   self.class_eval do
     define_method "example" do |x|
     end
   end
 end
```